# Can floating point error cause 'a/(double)b >= a/b' to fail?

Tags: java, floating-point

Can `result` ever be false because `4 / 2.0` may return something like `1.99999999`?  More generally than the title:

```
int a = // any valid int
int b = // any valid int
boolean result = (a/(double)b) >= a/b;
```

If this is possible, can anyone provide an example of `a` and `b`?  If this isn't possible, is there any java or floating point specification which proves this?

I wrote this logic a few minutes ago, and suddenly worried about it breaking.  I have been unable to break it, but I'm wondering if it's guaranteed across all JVMs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a` and `b` are positive `int` values, then `a/(double)b >= a/b`.

I use the following premises, along with understood semantics, such as that the `int` value of `a/b` will be converted to `double` for the comparison with the other operand of `>=`.

Premises:

- The range of `int` is [-2,147,483,648, 2,147,483,648).
- `double` is IEEE 754 64-bit binary.
- The rounding mode is round-to-nearest.
- All floating-point operations, particularly division, conform to IEEE 754.
- The integer `a/b` truncates toward zero.

Notation:

- *a* is the mathematical value of `a`.
- *b* is the mathematical value of `b`.
- Mathematical expressions, such as *a*/*b*, are exact, as distinct from computed expressions such as `a/b`.
- Let *L* be the value produced for `a/(double)b`.
- Let *R* be the value produced for `a/b`.

Proof:

- All `int` values are representable in `double`, so IEEE 754 requires that converting `int` to `double` be exact.
- Therefore, `(double) a` and `(double) b` produce *a* and *b* exactly, and `a/(double)b` produces *a*/*b* correctly rounded to the nearest `double`.
- Since *R* is *a*/*b* truncated toward zero, and *a*/*b* is positive, *R* is floor(*a*/*b*).
- The greatest *a*/*b* can be is 2,147,483,647/1 = 2,147,483,647. Each integer at this magnitude and below is exactly representable as a `double`.
- *L* is the `double` nearest *a*/*b*. If *L* is reduced by rounding, it is reduced to the next lower `double`. Since all integers at this magnitude are representable, floor(*a*/*b*) is representable, so *L* is at least floor(*a*/*b*).
- Therefore *L* ≥ *R*.
- The conversion of *R* to `double` is exact, so the comparison of *L* to *R* with `>=` produces the same result as the mathematical *L* ≥ *R*.

Comment: Thanks for the great and thorough response!

Answer (score 2):

For negative numbers, it fails for a = -10, b = 3.

For positive inputs only, I think you are safe.

Let x be the real number result of dividing a by b.

First consider the case where x is representable as an int. It is also representable as a double, and both calculations return x.

Now suppose x is not an int. The question is whether the absolute value of the rounding error difference between x and a/(double b) can ever exceed the truncation error for a/b. It cannot.

The truncation error t = x - a/b must be at least 1/b. x cannot be bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE/b, so t/x is at least 1/Integer.MAX_VALUE. That is much greater than the maximum rounding error on a correctly rounded double calculation.

Answer (score 0):

`4 / 2.0` must return `2.0` because floating-point division is exact.

Negative numbers may cause your comparison to fail, though.  Note that `-1/2 = 0` while `-1.0/2.0 = -0.5`.

Comment: +1 for the example.  However, "floating-point division division is exact" needs some qualification; what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Also because those are binary digits, no? `4 / 2.0` is `4 * 2^(-1)` which, IIRC, is how floats are stored.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The division of two floating-point numbers always returns the closest floating-point number to the quotient.

Comment: Can you expand on the definition of "exact"?  I assume that calculating `1/3` will lead to something like "0.33333..." to some amount of precision, but will never equal the true "exact" mathematical value of `1/3`.

Comment: @tmyklebu In other words it is *not* exact. It can't be, without infinite precision. And negative numbers have nothing to do with the 'failure' in your last example.

Comment: Perhaps it is sufficient to say division is exact given an exact decimal representation exists?  Which, of course, is true for all examples I would care about breaking `double >= int` expected behavior, due to the `int` on the right side.

Comment: @EJP: To be pedantic, that's the rounding, not the division.

Comment: @CoryKendall: Floating-point is binary, so no.  If an exact binary representation exists, you get it.  Otherwise, you get the nearest floating-point number.  Contrary to popular belief, there's no voodoo in the specification of floating-point math.

Comment: `-1/2 = 0` because you are dividing an `int` by an `int` so the result is cast to an `int`, I don't think it has anything to do with being negative

Comment: The term used in the IEEE 754 standard is “correctly rounded”. The produced result is generally not mathematically exact, but it is the mathematically exact result correctly rounded according to the rounding mode. In round-to-nearest mode, that is the nearest representable result, with ties toward the even low bit. There are other modes which produces results farther away.

Comment: @JasonSperske: This **is** related to the numerator being negative.  If everything's positive, then it's always true that `((double)num/(double)den) >= num/den`.  Not so if `num` or `den` is negative.

Comment: @tmyklebu We *are* being pedantic: it's a pedantic question; but 1/2 is zero regardless of any rounding, because of the properties of integer division, and the absolute value of 1.0/2.0 is 0.5 regardless of the sign, and also regardless of rounding, because there isn't any.